# Red, White and Pink

Tags: logical-deduction

R - Red, W - White, P - Pink

If:
$R + R = R + R + R + R$
$R + W = P + P + P + P$
$P + P = R + W + P + P$

What is $R + P$?

Hint:

> Mirabilis Jalapa

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Feel free to take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> $R + P = R + P + R + P$

Desc:

> It's the genes of flowers. $rr = R$, $rw = P$, $ww = W$. The possible combinations of $rr + rw$ is $rr$, $rw$, $rr$, $rw$.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! You can take a quick [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn your first badge. I have also reformatted the characters in your answer so that they will render nicely.